# Django - variables in include file not recognized

Tags: python, django, variables, django-templates, include

I am using djano 1.8.1 and python 2.7.

On two of my template pages I have the same set of variables.

So I decided to create an `{% include %}` page that holds these variables and then add the `{% include %}` tag on the required pages to call the variables.

However, when I set up the include file and cut and pasted the variables to the include file and added the include tag to the templates, the variables are not recognized.

No error is given, the variables are not displayed. I have checked that the path of the `{% include %}` tag is correct.

Is there something I have done incorrectly?

Here is the contents of the inlcude file:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Achievement Details" as var_details_name01 %}
{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05 %}
{% language "de" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_de %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "es-419" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_es_419 %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "en-CA" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_en_CA %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "en-GB" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_en_GB %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "fr-CA" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_fr_CA %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "it" %}{% trans "Type" as var_details_name05_it %}{% endlanguage %}
{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06 %}
{% language "de" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_de %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "es-419" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_es_419 %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "en-CA" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_en_CA %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "en-GB" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_en_GB %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "fr-CA" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_fr_CA %}{% endlanguage %}
{% language "it" %}{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name06_it %}{% endlanguage %}
{% trans "Achievement" as var_details_name07 %}
{% trans "Suggestion" as var_details_name04 %}
```

Here is the include tag with the correct location on my template file:

```
{% block extra_head %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/details_common.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    {% include "user_details/achievement_details_variables.html" %}

    {% include "headline/headline_with_toggle_help_icon.html" %}
    {% include "user_details/help_resume_details.html" %}
    ......
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you loaded the i18n library at the top of the include template?

Comment: solarissmoke, Yes I have loaded the i18n tag.

Comment: We probably need to the the actual code you are using in the include and parent template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `{% include %}` tag is html, which means that you can't define variables (or blocks) in an included template.

Comment: We tend to put these kinds of variables in the context, but it should be possible to create another layer of templates that you can extend from (and which defines the variables).

Comment: thanks again. that has given me something to work from.